# Try to make ACY Mailing newsletter archive view look more like a blog

Tags: joomla-4.x, menu-item, category-blog, menu-parameters

I am using ACY to create and send newsletters -  I am using their "menu newsletter archive view" ([https://www.beeswaxcandleshop.com/home/newsletters/archive/listing.html]) - The page looks rather simple, but works. Previously I posted all my emails as a blog and could add images, borders and lots of things to make the page look better.

Is there any way I could change a class on the menu, add an image from an email (joomla 4 only), put the menu in an article? What can I do to make the display look better?

I cannot seem to copy the html of the newsletter (I dont think acy wants me to - they want me to use their menu archive.

? Somehow copy the html of the email to an article?
? Add code to spice up the page?
? Insert the menu item in a module? (then I can put image on the page)
? Any other idea?

Comment: Have you just tried to change CSS only ?

Comment: Where would I find the css of the menu item?   I am not experienced with css, although I have added some to the template in the past.